# MIME type switched from "image/jpeg" to "image/png"

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

The following 2 code snippets demonstrate the problem I ran into with the NEW Google Drive Android API / Google Play Services 4.2 (libver 15). Or is it a feature I don't know about? All error checking and initialization is removed in order to keep the code simple.

1/ I create a picture of "image/jpeg" MIME type;

```
GoogleApiClient mGAC;
byte[] jpgBuffer;
DriveFolder fldr;

ContentsResult rslt = Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGAC).await();
Contents cont = rslt.getContents();
cont.getOutputStream().write(jpgBuffer);
MetadataChangeSet meta = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
  .setTitle("foo.jpg").setMimeType("image/jpeg")
  .build();
fldr.createFile(mGAC, meta, cont);
```

Everything is nice and dandy in the Drive. Image is there, looking great, I can even send it to my mom. But this is not what I'm after. I would like to retrieve it in another part of my Android app.

2/ So I try this:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(
  Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
).build();
MetadataBufferResult rslt = Drive.DriveApi.query(mGAC, query).await();
for (Metadata md : rslt.getMetadataBuffer()) {
  Log.d("TAG", md.getTitle() + " " + md.getMimeType());
}
```

Result: big, fat NOTHING.

I'm not giving up, so the next logical step is to look for ANY file. And the file "foo.jpg" I saved in step 1/ is showing as "image/png" MIME type.

Comment: did you try with mimetype as "image/*". This way it will take care of any image format

Comment: The question is very specific to the "Google Drive Android API" and there is no wildcard support there AFAIK.

Comment: We'll take a look at this, but is there a chance that the binary data you are uploading is actually in the png format?

Comment: You beat me to it by 7 minutes. So it could in the end be an argument about the ownership of the MIME metadata field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystery is solved. **IT IS A FEATURE!** The "jpgBuffer" in

```
cont.getOutputStream().write(jpgBuffer);
```

actually contains PNG binary data. So even if my app specified "image/jpeg" MIME type, Google after snooping through my (my user's) data decided to correct MIME type to "image/png". It should also be noted that it happens with some delay, making the debugging process even more mysterious.