# How to programmatically modify Google Drive photo metadata (EXIF)?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-photos

I have a lot of photos uploaded on Google Photos and synced with Drive that have the wrong date/time (The camera used to take them had the wrong date/time set and so the files all have the wrong EXIF information). I am trying to correct the date/time with a script directly in drive.

I can successfully extract the "date taken" using file.imageMediaMetadata.date, parse and convert to a Date and add a delta in milliseconds.

However I haven't found any way to push/write the modified date back to Drive?

Interestingly I noticed that Google appears to use photos' EXIF date for the file last updated date.

Before I give up, fix the files locally and re-upload them all, anyone know how or if this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible the way you want to do it. The EXIF metadata is in the header of the jpeg file, i.e. in the GooDrive universe it is **inside of the file content**. It is my belief that GooDrive reads this content (when mimetype indicates there is something to snoop for) and saves/indexes jpeg metadata to it's own copy, giving you 'read-only' access to this metadata copy. I know this is happening since I've run into [this mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868835/mime-type-switched-from-image-jpeg-to-image-png/21886776#21886776) a long time ago.

So the only way to do it, is to read (download) the file content, modify the EXIF metadata in the jpeg file and upload (update content of) the file. The new version of GooEXIF metadata will appear with some delay.

Good Luck